# Print all occurrences of vowels in a sentence

Tags: java, string, return, append

I wrote a method that should print all vowels in the sentence. But it seems that my code only returns one occurrence of a vowel. I need to return all the occurrences in a string. How do I make the output an appended string?

```
public String getVowels() {
    for (int i=0; i <MyString.str.length(); i++) {
        c = MyString.str.charAt(i);
        if ((MyString.str.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
            (MyString.str.charAt(i) == 'e') ||
            (MyString.str.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
            (MyString.str.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
            (MyString.str.charAt(i) == 'u')) {

            vowels = String.valueOf(c);
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're replacing the vowels `String` each time instead of updating it (appending).

Try this:

```
vowels += String.valueOf(c);
```

The whole code would look like this:

```
public String getVowels() {

    String myString = "testString";

    String vowels = "";
    for (int i=0; i < myString.length();i++) {
        if((myString.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
            (myString.charAt(i) == 'e') ||
            (myString.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
            (myString.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
            (myString.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
            vowels += String.valueOf(myString.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}
```

Output:

```
ei
```

Note that you're only checking for letters in lower case and you forgot about *y*.

**SPOILER**

This can be done in a bit more elegant way:

```
public void vowelsTest() {
    System.out.println(getVowels("MY FIRST test STRING on STACK overFLOW"));
}

public Collection<Character> getVowels(final String testString) 
{
    String allVowels = "aAeEiIoOuUyY";

    Collection<Character> vowelsInString = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char letter : testString.toCharArray()) {
        if (allVowels.indexOf(letter) >= 0) {
            vowelsInString.add(letter);
        }
    }

    return vowelsInString;
}
```

This will result in:

```
[Y, I, e, I, o, A, o, e, O]
```

If you would like only one instance of every vowel then you simply change `ArrayList` to `HashSet`, and that's all.

Output for `HashSet`:

```
[e, A, o, O, Y, I]
```

And if you need only one instance of every vowel no matter if upper/lower case you can substitute the line with `add` to:

```
vowelsInString.add(String.valueOf(letter).toLowerCase().charAt(0));
```

Which will result in:

```
[e, a, o, y, i]
```

Comment: @javabeginner Glad I could help. I've edited my answer with a litle bit more elegant way of solving this - check it out if you want.
Also - if this anwer solved your problem you can always accept it.

Comment: `y` is not always a vowel :) [Is the letter Y a vowel or a consonant?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant)

Comment: @DavidPostill you can ommit that then ;) In my language it's always a vowel.